# Spark aggregate rows with custom function

Tags: apache-spark

To make it simple, let's assume we have a dataframe containing the following data:

```
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|firstName |lastName |Phone     |Address   |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|firstName1|lastName1|info1     |info2     |
|firstName1|lastName1|myInfo1   |dummyInfo2|
|firstName1|lastName1|dummyInfo1|myInfo2   |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

How can I merge all rows grouping by (firstName,lastName) and keep in the columns Phone and Address only data starting by "my" to get the following :

```
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|firstName |lastName |Phone     |Address   |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|firstName1|lastName1|myInfo1   |myInfo2   |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Maybe should I use agg function with a custom UDAF? But how can I implement it?

Note: I'm using Spark 2.2 along with Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only two columns involved, filtering and join can be used instead of UDF:

```
val df = List(
  ("firstName1", "lastName1", "info1", "info2"),
  ("firstName1", "lastName1", "myInfo1", "dummyInfo2"),
  ("firstName1", "lastName1", "dummyInfo1", "myInfo2")
).toDF("firstName", "lastName", "Phone", "Address")

val myPhonesDF = df.filter($"Phone".startsWith("my"))
val myAddressDF = df.filter($"Address".startsWith("my"))

val result = myPhonesDF.alias("Phones").join(myAddressDF.alias("Addresses"), Seq("firstName", "lastName"))
    .select("firstName", "lastName", "Phones.Phone", "Addresses.Address")
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
|firstName |lastName |Phone  |Address|
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
|firstName1|lastName1|myInfo1|myInfo2|
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
```

For many columns, when only one row expected, such construction can be used:

```
  val columnsForSearch = List("Phone", "Address")
  val minExpressions = columnsForSearch.map(c => min(when(col(c).startsWith("my"), col(c)).otherwise(null)).alias(c))
  df.groupBy("firstName", "lastName").agg(minExpressions.head, minExpressions.tail: _*)
```

Output is the same.

UDF with two parameters example:

```
  val twoParamFunc = (firstName: String, Phone: String) => firstName + ": " + Phone
  val twoParamUDF = udf(twoParamFunc)
  df.select(twoParamUDF($"firstName", $"Phone")).show(false)
```

Comment: It was just an example to make it simple, but in real my dataframe contains more than 40 cols ... But thank you anyway

Comment: Here we apply min function to get only one value. What about if I have multiple values for the same Column starting with "my" and I'm supposed to launch an exception or do some logic to choose which one I should keep ? (The logic is the same for all the columns)

Comment: For chose logic UDF is required, if "min" or similar ("max", etc.) are not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupBy` and `collect_set` aggregation function and use a `udf` function *to filter in the first string that starts with "my"*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def myudf = udf((array: Seq[String]) => array.filter(_.startsWith("my")).head)

df.groupBy("firstName ", "lastName")
  .agg(myudf(collect_set("Phone")).as("Phone"), myudf(collect_set("Address")).as("Address"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
|firstName |lastName |Phone  |Address|
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
|firstName1|lastName1|myInfo1|myInfo2|
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful